# One artifact missing after deploying from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

My jenkins job produces 125 .deb packages which I publish to three different paths in one repo:

```
def artifactory = Artifactory.server('artifactory.riftio.com')

uploadSpec = """{
            "files" : [
                {
                    "pattern" : "core/mano/src/core_mano-build/*.deb",
                    "target" : "debian-local-debug/pool/main/",
                    "props" : "deb.distribution=xenial;deb.component=main;deb.architecture=amd64"
                },
                {
                    "pattern" : "core/enablement/src/core_enablement-build/*.deb",
                    "target" : "debian-local-debug/pool/proprietary/",
                    "props" : "deb.distribution=xenial;deb.component=main;deb.architecture=amd64"
                },
                {
                    "pattern" : "ext/vnfs/src/ext_vnfs-build/*.deb",
                    "target" : "debian-local-debug/pool/vnfs/",
                    "props" : "deb.distribution=xenial;deb.component=main;deb.architecture=amd64"
                },
                {
                    "pattern" : "toolchain/src/toolchain-build/*.deb",
                    "target" : "debian-local-debug/pool/main/",
                    "props" : "deb.distribution=xenial;deb.component=main;deb.architecture=amd64"
                }
            ]
}"""
buildInfo = artifactory.upload(uploadSpec)
buildInfo.retention maxBuilds: 20, deleteBuildArtifacts: true
artifactory.publishBuildInfo(buildInfo)
```

occasionally, one package fails to show up in the index and is un-downloadable. I can see it from the builds view, but not from the repo view and searching does not find it.

I see this error in the artifactory logs (with a few lines of context):

```
2018-11-09 16:23:23,688 [ajp-nio-8019-exec-1367] [INFO ] (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:376) - Deploy to 'debian-local-debug:pool/vnfs/rw.ext.vnfs-6.2.0.2.96097-Linux-tg_vrouter_ts_nsd-1.0.deb' Content-Length: 0
2018-11-09 16:23:23,690 [ajp-nio-8019-exec-1369] [INFO ] (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:376) - Deploy to 'debian-local-debug:pool/vnfs/rw.ext.vnfs-6.2.0.2.96097-Linux-tg_bigip_ts_nsd-1.0.deb' Content-Length: 5710
2018-11-09 16:23:23,740 [ajp-nio-8019-exec-1382] [INFO ] (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:376) - Deploy to 'debian-local-debug:pool/vnfs/rw.ext.vnfs-6.2.0.2.96097-Linux-tg_vrouter_ts_nsd-1.0.deb' Content-Length: 18884
2018-11-09 16:23:23,760 [art-exec-207331] [INFO ] (o.a.a.d.DebianServiceImpl:194) - Finished calculation of Debian metadata for distribution 'xenial' in repo 'debian-local-debug'. took 1121 ms
2018-11-09 16:23:23,760 [art-exec-207331] [INFO ] (o.a.a.d.DebianServiceImpl:191) - Starting calculation of Debian metadata for distribution 'xenial' in repo 'debian-local-debug'.
2018-11-09 16:23:23,762 [art-exec-207331] [INFO ] (o.j.r.d.i.a.DebianIncrementalAutomaticRepoIndexer:85) - Indexing all required packages of distribution xenial on repo debian-local-debug
2018-11-09 16:23:23,763 [art-exec-207331] [WARN ] (o.j.r.d.e.DpkgMetadataExtractor:206) - Can't read Artifact at path pool/vnfs/rw.ext.vnfs-6.2.0.2.96097-Linux-tg_vrouter_ts_nsd-1.0.deb --> Failed to retrieve resource debian-local-debug:pool/vnfs/rw.ext.vnfs-6.2.0.2.96097-Linux-tg_vrouter_ts_nsd-1.0.deb: Could not get resource stream. Path 'pool/vnfs/rw.ext.vnfs-6.2.0.2.96097-Linux-tg_vrouter_ts_nsd-1.0.deb' not found in debian-local-debug
```

The two records for one file, the first with content-length:0 and the second with the correct content-length, look like the problem to me. The indexer is running before the upload is done. This feels like a bug, but since it is inconsistent, it will be very hard to nail down.

Any suggestions? I am contemplating splitting this into 3 uploads but that has ramifications downstream when I go to promote it. I also shortened the uploadSpec .. the real one has 18 parts, not just 4. Should I pre-collect the files in 3 directories to shorten the spec?